# How to add instances from dbpedia to ontology

Tags: insert, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to add all countries to my ontology from dbpedia. However, it says that no countries were added. I am using GraphDB for this. I saw another post here that had the format to what I should use, but I still couldn't make it work. Can someone help me? Here is my query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://www.dbpedia.org/ontology>
PREFIX dbr: <http://www.dbpedia.org/resource>

INSERT 
  { ?s ?p ?o }
WHERE
  { SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> 
    {
      ?s rdf:type dbo:Country.
      ?s ?p ?o.
    }
  }
```

Comment: both prefix declarations `dbr` and `dbo` are wrong and since you're using `dbo` in your query the result is empty. A trailing `/` is missing, i.e. it should be  `http://www.dbpedia.org/ontology/` and `http://www.dbpedia.org/resource/`

Comment: by the way, you won't get all triples about countries as public DBpedia endpoint has a resultset limit of 10000 for a single request.